# Leer respuesta json en Axios Laravel Vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Tengo un método que captura la información que envía la vista vue (Profile.vue) mediante un PUT generado por Axios, el problema radica en lo siguiente, cuando los datos se actualizan (mediante el metodo myProfile del controlador UserController), axios captura la información del retorno en json desde el metodo, y el mensaje de exito es mostrado, pero cuando hay una error, Axios no captura la información del json de error y me alega lo siguiente:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

Entiendo que me está alegando por las variables que tengo en el catch de Axios que no tienen információn

El código de myProfile es el siguiente:

```
    $profile = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $profile->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $profile->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $profile->gender = $request->gender;
    $profile->description = $request->description;
    if($profile->update())
    {
        return response()->json([
                'status' => 'Muy bien!',
                'msg' => 'Datos actualizados correctamente.',
                'cod' => 201
        ]);
    }
    else{
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'Ocurrio un error!',
                'msg' => 'Ocurrio un error al actualizar la información.',
                'cod' => 400
                ]);
    }
```

Sección Axios de Profile.vue

```
axios.put('/dashboard/profile', value)
            .then((response) => {
                let title = response.data.status;
                let body = response.data.msg;
                this.displayNotificationSuccess(title, body);
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                let title = response.data.status;
                let body = response.data.msg;
                this.displayNotificationError(title,body);
            })
```

Como comentaba anteriormente, cuando hay éxito en el controlador, Axios lee y muestra el mensaje json, cuando hay error, no lo hace.

¿Donde estoy fallando que Axios no puede mostrar el mensaje de erro json que viene desde el controlador?

Ocupo Laravel 5.6, Vuejs 2 y Axios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que no está pasando el `status code` a su respuesta desde Laravel por lo que siempre obtendrá un status `200` de `OK` , es por esta razón que nunca entrará al `catch` desde axios .

Para solucionar el status code se pasa como segundo parámetro a la función `->json()` de la siguiente forma.

```
response()->json([], statuscode)
```

La lista completa de los códigos están en `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`

Entonces su solución sería.

**Laravel**

```
if($profile->update())
{
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'Muy bien!',
        'msg' => 'Datos actualizados correctamente.',
    ],201);
}
else{
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'Ocurrio un error!',
        'msg' => 'Ocurrio un error al actualizar la información.',
    ],400);
}
```

**Axios**

```
axios.put('/putroute')
   .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
    })
   catch(error => {
        //obtener el status _(error 400)
        console.log(error.response.data.status);
   })
```

Comment: Aún así, se muestra el toast pero sin el mensaje y en la consola de chrome me arroja un error 500, pienso que quizás pueda ser que está mal hecho el método que recibe el PUT de Axios.

Comment: @Felipe si recibe ese error, posiblemente sea eso o un error no visto en su pregunta. Igual el código de Laravel se puede mejorar ,para esta respuesta no me centré en eso solo la parte de los status code.

Comment: Claro, cuando paso un dato vacío, el validador del controlador hace su trabajo y  manda el error, la pregunta es  ¿como puedo controlar la respuesta para que la pueda tomar axios como error?

Comment: ¿Cómo está haciendo la validación ? por un formRequest o directamente desde el controlador debería retornar un status code 422 si hubieran errores de validación, mi respuesta seguiría funcionando solo que en lugar de status accedería a `error.response.data.errors`

Comment: Pasa por la validación tradicional del controlador ($this->validate($request....), la respuesta se la asigno a una variable que luego paso por un if (if($validado)....), si no hay errores manda un json 200, si hay errores responde con un json 422 o 401. El punto que no sé como pasar eso directamente a Axios para que no salga el error en la consola se chrome.

Comment: @Felipe lo que comenta no está en la pregunta , es difícil adivinar lo que intenta hacer. No tiene por qué hacer un if si la validación pasa simplemente ejecutará la siguiente linea caso contrario simplemente retornará la respuesta con el status code 422 y el catch si lo podría obtener.

Comment: justamente esas cosas no sabía, llevo un poco mas de 3 semanas programando en Laravel. Lo que necesito saber ahora es como ocultar ese 422 que me aparece en la consola de chrome.